# Chazan's position and path when taking out the Torah?

Tags: torah-service, chazzan-prayer-leader

When taking out the Torah from the ark, what is the proper procedure in these areas?

- On Shabbat, the Chazan faces the cong. (back to the ark) when saying *Shema* and *Echad Elokeinu*. Then he turns to face the ark to say *Gadlu* and turns again to walk off the bimah. In which direction should he turn - clockwise or counter-clockwise?
- When walking from the ark to the Torah table, which side of the shul should he walk? To his right or left?

Sources for both, please.

Answer (score 4):

Could not find the answer to clockwise vs. counter-clockwise, but found the answer to your second question in Aruch HaShulchan Orach Chayim 282:1: - [סימן רפב - דיני קריאת התורה והמפטיר בשבת](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01582.html#HtmpReportNum0200_L2)

> והש"ץ נוטל הספר תורה ופניו כלפי העם, ואומר בקול: 'שמע ישראל וגו',
>   והעם עונים אחריו. ואחר כך אומר: 'אחד הוא אלקינו, גדול אדונינו קדוש
>   שמו' ... והציבור
>   עונין אחריו 'אחד הוא אלקינו וכו'.ואחר כך מחזיר הש"ץ פניו כלפי ההיכל
>   ושוחה קצת, ואומר 'גדלו לד' אתי וגו', והציבור עונין 'לך ד' הגדולה וגו',
>   'על הכל יתגדל ויתקדש וכו', **והולך הש"ץ עם הספר תורה לימין**

My translation:

> ...and the *chazan* takes the *sefer torah* and faces the
>   congregation, and says out loud "*shema yisrael* etc.," and the
>   congregation answers after him. Afterwards he says "*Echad Hu*
>   etc."... and the congregation answers after him "*Echad Hu* etc.".
>   Afterwards, the *chazan* returns to face the ark and bows slightly,
>   and says "*gadlu* etc." and the congregation answers "*licha Hashem*
>   etc.", "*al hakol* etc.", **and the *chazan* walks with the *sefer
>   torah* to the right**...

It is interesting to note that the Mishnah Berurah does not mention the practice of turning to face the ark when saying *Gadlu*, nor bowing. However, he does say in [OC 134:13](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.134.13?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all) that one should lift the Torah during each of the three *pesukim*:

> **וצריך להגביה התורה ג"פ דהיינו בשעה שאומר שמע וגו' אחד וגו'
>   גדלו וגו'** [מ"א בשם מ"ס]:‏

My translation:

> ... and he is required to lift the *torah* three times, namely during
>   the time when he says "*shema* etc." "*Echad* etc." and "*gadlu* etc."

Comment: This a partial answer, as it answers just the 2nd question. That's great. Can you edit further and leave only the Hebrew part that you bolded? The rest seems superfluous.

Comment: @DanF Edited. Everything I left I thought was relevant.

Comment: Is the Aruch HaShulchan the first historical source to mention this minhag? Is it possible to know where does this originate from?